# Ruby Time.parse gives me out of range error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

I am using Time.parse to create a Time object from a string.

For some reason

```
Time.parse("05-14-2009 19:00")
```

causes an argument our of range error, whereas

```
Time.parse("05-07-2009 19:00")
```

does not

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess would be that its expecting the second part of the string (the 14) to be the month.

[This link may help you parse it.](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/184961)

Answer (score 26):

If you know the format of the string use:

```
Time.strptime(date, format, now=self.now) {|year| ...}
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Time.html#M000266

It will solve your problem and will probably be faster than `Time.parse`.

EDIT:

Looks like they took `strptime` from Time class, but it called `Date.strptime` anyway. If you are on Rails you can do:

```
Date.strptime("05-14-2009 19:00","%m-%d-%Y %H:%M").to_time
```

if you use pure ruby then you need:

```
require 'date'
d=Date._strptime("05-14-2009 19:00","%m-%d-%Y %H:%M")

Time.utc(d[:year], d[:mon], d[:mday], d[:hour], d[:min], 
         d[:sec], d[:sec_fraction], d[:zone])
```

See also: [Date and Time formating issues in Ruby on Rails](http://blog.nominet.org.uk/tech/2007/06/14/date-and-time-formating-issues-in-ruby-on-rails/).

Comment: strptime looks cool but I get an undefined method for Time.strptime and I need a time object

Comment: ...here is the usage Time.strptime(date_time['value'], "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M")

Comment: Looks like strptime does not exist in Time anymore, see edit for alternative

Comment: thanks miguel, that solution looks good. i ended up using this statement: fixed_date_time = "#{$2}-#{$1}-#{$3} #{$4}:#{$5}" if date_time['value']  =~ /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2})/ 

because i saw your post late.  i don't plan on changing it because it works and it may even be faster.  anyway, voted you up but had to give the answer to the first commenter since his link solved my problem.

Comment: I don't think this solution is faster as it has to call _parse anyway, parse implementation use heuristics checking a lot of cases. Additionally, your code will fail when 1.9 is out as they changed to use ISO date formats. My solution will not fail as uses the ruby standard date formating mechanisms.

Comment: You can also use DateTime's strptime, since Date.strptime won't accept a valid hourly time(just a date).
`DateTime.strptime("05-14-2009 19:00","%m-%d-%Y %H:%M").to_time`

Answer (score 15):

It's because of the heuristics of `Time#parse`.

And it's due to anglo-american formats.

With dashes '-' it expects mm-dd-yyyy, with slashes '/' it expects dd/mm/yyyy.

This behaviour *changes* intentionally in 1.9. to accomplish eur, iso and jp date standards.

Comment: I think the formats are mixed up here. With dashes `-` it expects `dd-mm-yyyy` or `yyyy-mm-dd` (in the latter case, the first two `y` s are optional), with slashes `/` it expects `mm/dd/yyyy` (here the first two `y` s are optional, too).

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I don't see the described behavior. I'm using 1.9.2p136. Time#parse interprets the input as dd/mm/yyyy whether I use '-' or '/'.

Comment: My comment above is not correct. For Ruby 1.8.6 and 1.8.7 it seems to be `mm/dd/yyyy` and for 1.9.2 it's `dd/mm/yyyy`. Both Rubys parse the dash-format as `dd-mm-yyyy`. But I am not 100% sure if that's only because of the Ruby version, or if other factors affect the parsing, too; like the computer's date-, time-, region- and/or timezone-settings.

Answer (score 3):

You probably do not need it to solve this problem but I still recommend checking out the natural language date/time parser [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/), it has saved me a lot of work a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably expecting Day-Month-Year format, so your first value is trying to specify the 5th day of the 14th month.